# Xamarin Forms : How controls to retain size proportionally over multiple resolutions of same or different device

Tags: xamarin.forms

I know that similar questions are posted over and over again and i have read articles for sizing of controls like in http://www.xforms-kickstarter.com/ and many others but i have never came to real answer how for instance particular control in Xamarin Forms like Button, Entry or Label behave differently in the same device in different resolutions? If there any method to calculate the size of a control to retain or scale proportionally its size to the resolution of device please answer...

Comment: Why don't you use the "protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)" of ContentPage? You can get a size of your screen when the size of the screen is changed. And you would set a size of your controls.

Comment: Thanks for reply i will check ....

Comment: But the best solution is using a different type of layouts like AbsoluteLayout, StackLayout...etc more effectively. I think you could achieve anything you want if you use these Layouts better.

Comment: But if it's the case that can't be resolved by using Layouts, you should find an alternative solution like I said before.

Comment: Point is that  the app i'am working on has complex UI and i already designed it with various  layouts such as Grid  and Stack in some cases nested, also using negative margins to really position precisely controls (i have put some buttons in navigation drawer) also Vertical Options and Horizontal Options mostly,but still design look nicely on Samsung Galaxy S7 on Genymotion 1200x1920,320 dpi but on another resolution some controls are missing(like buttons on Login screen), or are overlapping  and i'am looking for solution for every another design that ill make to be persistent

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess your UI items are many and are located so tightly. And you don't use a ScrollView on purpose to resolve that situation. Normally people use a ScrollView to resolve that case. I sympathize your situation.